# Ansible global variable in template

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I am having trouble getting my jinja2 template from ansible to be able to read a global variable set in `group_vars/all.yml`.

** My Question is **: How can I get my j2 template to be able to see global variables set within `group_vars/all.yml`? from my understanding, `group_vars/all` should apply to all groups.

My ansible project is as follows:

```
group_vars/
  all.yml

playbooks/
  roles/
    some-role/
      tasks/
        main.yml
      templates/
        template.conf.j2
  my-playbook.yml
```

#### tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: do it
  template:
    src: template.conf.j2
    dest: ...
```

#### templates/template.conf.j2

```
The global variable is: {{ GlobalVariable }}
```

#### group_vars/all.yml

```
GlobalVariable: something
```

When I run the playbook, I get an error when trying to write that template.

```
AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'GlobalVariable' is undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your `group_vars` folder inside `playbooks` folder and it should solve your problem.

Something like that:

```
playbooks/
  group_vars/
    all.yml
  roles/
    some-role/
      tasks/
        main.yml
      templates/
        template.conf.j2
  my-playbook.yml
```

Then no matter where you executing you `ansible-playbook -i hosts my-playbook.yml` command (outside of playbook or inside) it should work

Here is little more explanation with reference to the [source-code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/5f0f5363b6fcbd29013bcc9f84d01e60dbed95ca/lib/ansible/inventory/__init__.py#L653)

> ```
>    """
>     Loads variables from group_vars/<groupname> and host_vars/<hostname> in directories parallel
>     to the inventory base directory or in the same directory as the playbook.  Variables in the playbook
>     dir will win over the inventory dir if files are in both.
>     """
> ```

Comment: this is absolutely correct.  when I looked at the [standard directory layout](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout), i tried moving all my playbooks to project directory and it worked.  looks like it does base it off of adjacent folders.  thanks!